# Junit Data Driven test using only selected Datapoints

Tags: java, junit, data-driven

i have 3 datapoints of string array and 2 datapoints of integer array.

```
@DataPoint public static Integer[] xxx ={100,200};
@DataPoint public static Integer[] x ={-14,15};
@DataPoint public static String[] xx = new String[]{"de" ,"Y"};
@DataPoint public static String[] cityCode = new String[]{"de" ,"abc"};
 @DataPoint public static String[] city = new String[]{"de" ,"dfg"};


@Theory public void xxx(String[] result ,Integer[] checkdt )
```

when running this testcases it is taking 3 datapoints of string array,but i want to use only 2 datapoints of String array
how can i use only 2 datapoints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Assume](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assume.java) to filter the datapoints. At the beginning of the test, add something like:

```
@Theory public void xxx(String[] result ,Integer[] checkdt )  {
    Assume.assumeTrue("Y".equals(result[1]);
    // rest of test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding there is no selection of `specific DataPoint` to `specicfic Theory`.

Each `@Theory` will run against input parameters of `@DataPoint`.

Do you want filter DataPoint data You can assert that input data which you want and run rest.

Comment: how to fliter DataPoint data